# Spring stack overflow when using setter methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, stack-overflow

I have changed my mappers to inject via setter as spring documentation suggests to avoid a circular dependency however - I am still having the same issue. To this extent I get a stackoverflow excepetion when either of these mappers is called. I was under the impression using spring autowired tag as opposed to putting it in the constructor would solve this too but does not seem to work.

**The RolePersistenceMapper is a simple mapper and does not inject anything**

Stack overlflow exception:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.safeObjectAppend(MessageFormatter.java:302)
org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.deeplyAppendParameter(MessageFormatter.java:271)
org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(MessageFormatter.java:233)
org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(MessageFormatter.java:173)
ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.getFormattedMessage(LoggingEvent.java:298)
ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.prepareForDeferredProcessing(LoggingEvent.java:208)
ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.subAppend(OutputStreamAppender.java:212)
ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:182)
ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(OutputStreamAppender.java:103)
ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:88)
ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:48)
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:273)
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:260)
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:442)
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_1(Logger.java:414)
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.debug(Logger.java:507)
com.app.storage.persistence.mapper.RolePersistenceMapperHandler.mapFrom(RolePersistenceMapperHandler.java:42)
com.app.storage.persistence.mapper.RolePersistenceMapperHandler.mapFrom(RolePersistenceMapperHandler.java:12)
com.app.storage.persistence.mapper.constants.ListMapper.mapList(ListMapper.java:33)
com.app.storage.persistence.mapper.UserPersistenceMapperHandler.mapFrom(UserPersistenceMapperHandler.java:71)
com.app.storage.persistence.mapper.StorageItemPersistenceMapperHandler.mapFrom(StorageItemPersistenceMapperHandler.java:44)
com.app.storage.persistence.mapper.StorageItemPersistenceMapperHandler.mapFrom(StorageItemPersistenceMapperHandler.java:16)
com.app.storage.persistence.mapper.constants.ListMapper.mapList(ListMapper.java:33)
com.app.storage.persistence.mapper.UserPersistenceMapperHandler.mapFrom(UserPersistenceMapperHandler.java:73)
com.app.storage.persistence.mapper.StorageItemPersistenceMapperHandler.mapFrom(StorageItemPersistenceMapperHandler.java:44)
com.app.storage.persistence.mapper.StorageItemPersistenceMapperHandler.mapFrom(StorageItemPersistenceMapperHandler.java:16)
com.app.storage.persistence.mapper.constants.ListMapper.mapList(ListMapper.java:33)
com.app.storage.persistence.mapper.UserPersistenceMapperHandler.mapFrom(UserPersistenceMapperHandler.java:73)
com.app.storage.persistence.mapper.StorageItemPersistenceMapperHandler.mapFrom(StorageItemPersistenceMapperHandler.java:44)
com.app.storage.persistence.mapper.StorageItemPersistenceMapperHandler.mapFrom(StorageItemPersistenceMapperHandler.java:16)
```

These are my two mappers:

UserMapper:

```
/**
 * Implementation of {@link UserPersistenceMapper}
 */
    @Component
public class UserPersistenceMapperHandler implements UserPersistenceMapper, AbstractMapper<UserPersistenceModel, User> {

/** Logger. */
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserPersistenceMapper.class);

/** {@link RolePersistenceMapper} */
private RolePersistenceMapper rolePersistenceMapper;

/** {@link StorageItemPersistenceMapper} */
private StorageItemPersistenceMapper storageItemPersistenceMapper;

/** {@link ListMapper}. */
private ListMapper listMapper;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public UserPersistenceModel mapTo(final User user) {

    LOG.debug("Mapping user to persistence model.");

    UserPersistenceModel userPersistenceModel = null;
    if (user != null) {
        userPersistenceModel = new UserPersistenceModel();

        userPersistenceModel.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        userPersistenceModel.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        userPersistenceModel.setId(user.getId());
        userPersistenceModel.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        userPersistenceModel.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        userPersistenceModel.setRoles(listMapper.mapList((AbstractMapper) rolePersistenceMapper,
                                                         true, user.getRoles()));
    }

    LOG.debug("Successfully mapped user to persistence model");

    return userPersistenceModel;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public User mapFrom(final UserPersistenceModel userPersistenceModel) {

    LOG.debug("Mapping user persistence model to domain model.");

    User user = null;
    if (userPersistenceModel != null) {

        user = new User();
        user.setId(userPersistenceModel.getId());
        user.setEmail(userPersistenceModel.getEmail());
        user.setFirstName(userPersistenceModel.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(userPersistenceModel.getLastName());
        user.setPassword(userPersistenceModel.getPassword());
        user.setRoles(listMapper.mapList((AbstractMapper) rolePersistenceMapper, false,
                                         userPersistenceModel.getRoles()));
        user.setStorageItems(listMapper.mapList((AbstractMapper) storageItemPersistenceMapper, false,
                                                userPersistenceModel.getStorageItemPersistenceModelList()));
    }

    LOG.debug("Successfully mapped persistence model to domain model.");

    return user;
}

/**
 * Sets new {@link RolePersistenceMapper}.
 *
 * @param rolePersistenceMapper
 *         New value of {@link RolePersistenceMapper}.
 */
@Autowired
public void setRolePersistenceMapper(RolePersistenceMapper rolePersistenceMapper) {
    this.rolePersistenceMapper = rolePersistenceMapper;
}

/**
 * Sets new {@link StorageItemPersistenceMapper}.
 *
 * @param storageItemPersistenceMapper
 *         New value of {@link StorageItemPersistenceMapper}.
 */
@Autowired
public void setStorageItemPersistenceMapper(StorageItemPersistenceMapper storageItemPersistenceMapper) {
    this.storageItemPersistenceMapper = storageItemPersistenceMapper;
}

/**
 * Sets new {@link ListMapper}..
 *
 * @param listMapper
 *         New value of {@link ListMapper}..
 */
@Autowired
public void setListMapper(ListMapper listMapper) {
    this.listMapper = listMapper;
}
}
```

And my StorageItemPersistenceMapper:

```
/**
 * Implementation of {@link StorageItemPersistenceMapper}
 */
@Component
public class StorageItemPersistenceMapperHandler implements 
StorageItemPersistenceMapper,
    AbstractMapper<StorageItemPersistenceModel, StorageItem> {

/** Logger. */
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StorageItemPersistenceMapper.class);

/** {@link UserPersistenceMapper}. */
private UserPersistenceMapper userPersistenceMapper;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public StorageItem mapFrom(final StorageItemPersistenceModel storageItemPersistenceModel) {

    LOG.debug("Mapping storage item persistence model to domain model.");

    StorageItem storageItem = null;
    if (storageItemPersistenceModel != null) {

        storageItem = new StorageItem();
        storageItem.setDescription(storageItemPersistenceModel.getDescription());
        storageItem.setDateStored(storageItemPersistenceModel.getDateStored());
        storageItem.setImage(storageItemPersistenceModel.getImage());
        storageItem.setSize(storageItemPersistenceModel.getSize());
        storageItem.setBrand(storageItemPersistenceModel.getBrand());
        storageItem.setGrade(Grade.valueOf(storageItemPersistenceModel.getGrade()));
        if (storageItemPersistenceModel.getUserPersistenceModel() != null) {
            storageItem.setOwner(userPersistenceMapper.mapFrom(storageItemPersistenceModel
                                                                       .getUserPersistenceModel()));
        }
    }

    LOG.debug("Mapping storage item domain model to persistence model.");


    return storageItem;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public StorageItemPersistenceModel mapTo(final StorageItem storageItem) {

    LOG.debug("Mapping storage item domain model to persistence model.");

    StorageItemPersistenceModel storageItemPersistenceModel = null;
    if (storageItem != null) {
        storageItemPersistenceModel = new StorageItemPersistenceModel();
        storageItemPersistenceModel.setDescription(storageItem.getDescription());
        storageItemPersistenceModel.setSize(storageItem.getSize());
        storageItemPersistenceModel.setDateStored(storageItem.getDateStored());
        storageItemPersistenceModel.setImage(storageItem.getImage());
        storageItemPersistenceModel.setBrand(storageItem.getBrand());
        if (storageItem.getGrade() != null) {
            storageItemPersistenceModel.setGrade(storageItem.getGrade().name());
        }
        if (storageItem.getOwner() != null) {
            storageItemPersistenceModel.setUserPersistenceModel(userPersistenceMapper.mapTo(storageItem.getOwner
                    ()));
        }

    }

    LOG.debug("Mapping storage item persistence model to domain model.");

    return storageItemPersistenceModel;
}


/**
 * Sets new {@link UserPersistenceMapper}..
 *
 * @param userPersistenceMapper
 *         New value of {@link UserPersistenceMapper}..
 */
@Autowired
public void setUserPersistenceMapper(final UserPersistenceMapper userPersistenceMapper) {
    this.userPersistenceMapper = userPersistenceMapper;
}
}
```

And finally my listmapper abstract class:

```
@Component
public class ListMapper {

/**
 * Maps lists of objects.
 */
public <T, R> List<R> mapList(final AbstractMapper mapper, boolean isTo, final List<T> classA) {

    List<R> mappedObjectList = null;

    if (classA != null) {

        mappedObjectList = new ArrayList<R>();

        if (isTo) {
            for (final T classAObject : classA) {
                mappedObjectList.add((R) mapper.mapTo(classAObject));
            }
        } else {
            for (final T classAObject : classA) {
                mappedObjectList.add((R) mapper.mapFrom(classAObject));
            }
        }
    }

    return mappedObjectList;
}
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get the exception? Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Updated - hope that helps.

Comment: The problem is not Spring injection. It's how you map the objects itself. You have a bidirectional relationship between User and StorageItem, and while mapping them, you don't have an exit condition. So when mapping a user, it will go to map his storage items, then for each storage item it will map the user, which will map all storage items, which will then map the user for each item etc. etc.

Comment: I see. What would you recommend for mapping bidirectional objects?

Comment: What you could do, is to take the user, which is currently mapped, and give it to the storage mapper as argument somehow, so that the storage item mapper just uses that user object, and not maps the user completely fresh.